# JavaScript SUM Function Check

Tags: javascript, sum

everyone, I wanna create a "SUM" function on my own, but dunno what's going wrong on my code, can you anyone help me figure it out?

```
function range(start,end,step){
var countx = [];
if(step===undefined){
step=1;
for(start=1;start<=end;start+=step)
  countx.push(start);
console.log(countx);
}
else {
for(var i=start;i>=end;i+=step)
  countx.push(i);
console.log(countx);
}
}

function sum(arrayx){
var total=0;
for(var i=0;i<=arrayx.length;i++)
total+=console.log(array[i]);
return total;
}
```

**Results I want is**
console.log(sum(range(1,10)));
//-> 55

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0):

this is sample code for get sum of range if n =3 , result =6 [sum of 3+2+1]

```
function sumrange(n){
result =0;
while(n-->0){
result+=n;
}
return result;
}
```

if you want to sum from range

```
function sumrange(n,m){
result =0;
if(m>n){
while(m-->n){
result+=m;
    }
    return result;
}
}
```

Comment: Great!!! But is there any other way which can extract the value from the array first, and then add them together?

Comment: Yes, use array reduce.. var ar = [3,2,1,5,7]; ar.reduce((a,b)=>{return a+b}), this is the shortest code i can come up

Comment: `I wanna create a "SUM" function on my own`  I think it's a bit of a learning exercise, which I think is great, rather than writing code for him.

Comment: Yeah, i think reduce could be better and faster!

Answer (score 0):

You wasn't far off..

I've copied your code and fixed errors, placing comments were you made the mistakes..

```js
function range(start,end,step){
  var countx = [];
  if(step===undefined){
    step=1;
    for(start=1;start<=end;start+=step)
      countx.push(start);
  } else {
    //like pointed out by JiangangXiong, you >= would want to be <= too.  
    for(var i=start;i<=end;i+=step)
      countx.push(i);  
  }
  return countx; //don't forget to return
}

function sum(arrayx){
  var total=0;
  //this for loop wants to be < not <=
  for(var i=0;i < arrayx.length;i++) 
  //total+=console.log(array[i]);
  total += arrayx[i];
  return total;
}

console.log(sum(range(1,10)));
```

Comment: Really Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

**there can be many optimization done, but below is your code with Working modification**

```
function range(start,end,step){
        var countx = [];
        if(step===undefined){
          step=1;
          for(start;start<=end;start+=step)
            countx.push(start);
          console.log(countx);
        }
        else {
          for(var i=start;i>=end;i+=step)
            countx.push(i);
          console.log(countx);
        }
        return countx;
    }

    function sum(arrayx){
        var total=0;
        for(var i=0;i<arrayx.length;i++)
          total+=Number(arrayx[i]);
        return total;
    }
```

**Optimized code**

```
function range(start,end,step){
    var countx = [];
    step = step? step: 1;
    for(start;start<=end;start+=step)
        countx.push(start);
    return countx;
}

function sum(arrayx){
    return arrayx.reduce((total, item)=>{return total+= item});
}
```

Comment: Well, a bit strange, cause it still doesn't work now

Comment: @A.Kao also check optimized solution, hope this will help

Comment: with my answer, you will see up and down arrow, you can select up or down arrow to based on whether the answer was helpful to you.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up

Answer (score 0):

```
else {
    for(var i=start;i>=end;i+=step) {
      countx.push(i);
      console.log(countx);
   }
 }
```

why there is `i>=end`, not `i<=end`.

Comment: cause I want to make it count downward!

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce function of javascript

```js
function add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
function range(start, end, step) {
    var countx = [];
    if (step === undefined) {
        step = 1;
        for (start = 1; start <= end; start += step)
            countx.push(start);
    }
    else {
        for (var i = start; i >= end; i += step)
            countx.push(i);
    }
    var sum = countx.reduce(add, 0);

    
    console.log(sum);
}


range(1, 10);
```

Comment: Appreciated! But can you explain the ".reduce" method means? cause I am just a beginner....haven;t learned this yet

Comment: it will execute the function for each element of array. In simple temp loop through the array element

Comment: Ok, got it! appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

**Your code with corrections:**

```
function range(start,end,step){
    let countx = [];
    if(typeof step==='undefined'){
        step=1;
        for(let start=1;start<=end;start+=step){
            countx.push(start);
        }
    }
    else {
        for(let i=start;i>=end;i+=step)
          countx.push(i);
        }
    return countx;
}

function sum(arrayx){
    let total=0;
    for(let i=0;i<=arrayx.length-1;i++){
          total+= (+arrayx[i]);
    }
    return total;
}
console.log(sum(range(1,10)));
```

**Improved sum function with reduce:**

```
function sum(arrayx){
    return total = arrayx.reduce((sum,num) =>{
        return sum += num;
    });
}
```

Comment: Really Appreciated!

Comment: @A.Kao, here is an example of how to write the sum function with array reduce method.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function range(start,end,step){
    var countx = [];
    if(step===undefined){
      step=1;
      for(start=1;start<=end;start+=step)
        countx.push(start);
      console.log(countx);
    }
    else {
      for(var i=start;i>=end;i+=step)
        countx.push(i);
      console.log(countx);
    }
    return countx;
}

function sum(arrayx){
    var total=0;
    for(var i=0;i<arrayx.length;i++)
      total+=Number(arrayx[i]);
    return total;
}


console.log(sum(range(1,10)));
```

```js
function range(start,end,step){
    var countx = [];
    if(step===undefined){
      step=1;
      for(start=1;start<=end;start+=step)
        countx.push(start);
      console.log(countx);
    }
    else {
      for(var i=start;i>=end;i+=step)
        countx.push(i);
      console.log(countx);
    }
    return countx;
}

function sum(arrayx){
    var total=0;
    for(var i=0;i<arrayx.length;i++)
      total+=Number(arrayx[i]);
    return total;
}


console.log(sum(range(1,10)));
```